# A system of equations with Difference of Fifths

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a system of equations I thought of that I cannot seem to solve.
$x^5-y^5=168,$ $x-y=2.$
I can divide them to get $x^4+xy^3+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4=84,$ but that is as close I can get to the solution.
I want the rational solution and a way to solve it without a calculator, or a proof it is basically impossible to.

Comment: You can eliminate one variable by taking $y=x-2$ from the second equation and substituting into the first.

Comment: If you're looking to find exactly one solution, [you should stop trying](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E5-y%5E5%3D168,+x-y%3D2).

Comment: Good point. I want the rational solution.

Comment: Also, $x+y=A, xy=B$ can solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $y=x-2$ into the first equation:
$$
x^5-(x-2)^5=168.
$$
Let $x=z+1$:
$$
(z+1)^5-(z-1)^5=168.
$$
Expand and simplify:
$$
10z^4+20z^2+2=168.
$$
You should now be able to solve the last equation (it is quadratic in $z^2$).